# Owl Carousel not showing images in Django server

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, django-templates, owl-carousel

Well, as explained in the title, when I designed the site in plain css and html, it shows the images perfectly, here's the relevant code after calling the necessary files, and result IN PURE FRONTEND:

```html
<!-- ================= main slide ================= -->

<div class="owl-init slider-main owl-carousel" data-items="1" data-margin="1" data-nav="true" data-dots="false">
<div class="item-slide">
    <img src="img/banners/CDMX.jpg">

</div>
<div class="item-slide">
    <img src="img/banners/GDL.jpg">
</div>
<div class="item-slide">
    <img src="img/banners/MTY.png">
</div>
</div>

<!-- ============== main slidesow .end // ============= -->
</div> <!-- col.// -->
```

and the result:
[image: owlQuery01]

yet, here's the code in index.html after extending the base.html file and making sure all css an js files are correctly called:

```html
<!-- ================= ciudades slide ================= -->

<div class="owl-init slider-main owl-carousel"  data-margin="1" data-nav="true" data-dots="false">
    <div class="item-slide owl-item">
        <img src="{% static 'core/img/banners/MTY.png' %}">
    </div>

    <div class="item-slide owl-item">
        <img src="{% static 'core/img/banners/GDL.jpg' %} ">
    </div>
    
    <div class="item-slide owl-item ">
        <img src="{% static 'core/img/banners/CDMX.jpg' %}">
    </div>
</div>

<!-- ============== main slidesow .end // ============= -->
    </div> <!-- col.// -->
```

and this result:

[image: owlQuery2]

it shows the following result when analyzing the html result in the browser:

```html
<!-- ================= ciudades slide ================= -->

<div class="owl-init slider-main owl-carousel"  data-margin="1" data-nav="true" data-dots="false">
    <div class="item-slide owl-item">
        <img src="/static/core/img/banners/MTY.png">
    </div>

    <div class="item-slide owl-item">
        <img src="/static/core/img/banners/GDL.jpg ">
    </div>
    
    <div class="item-slide owl-item">
        <img src="/static/core/img/banners/CDMX.jpg">
    </div>
</div>

<!-- ============== main slidesow .end // ============= -->
    </div> <!-- col.// -->
```

and I will insert an image of the log so you see that the issue is not the source/path I'm using:

[image: owlQueryLog]

If any extra code or info is needed, I will be checking continously, thank you all very much...

Answer (score 0):

Create static files settings in `settings.py`

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),]
```

put this code in `urls.py`

```
if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: I didn't want to just paste all the code here, so maybe I didn't clear all that out, but I have already done that, I didn't have the  

`STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),]`

part though, so I added it and it's still not working.

Thank you very much for the answer, though.